# Can we use key to update an component linked to another component with the same key

Tags: reactjs, key, state, sql-update

I'm creating an website with differents product card and in the homepage I display **the tops products** and **all products avaible** in two differents component (**AllProduct.js & TopProduct.js**).

I creating my **top product Card** by mapping each item retrieved and adding **the productID as key** like this :

```
{props.deals.map(deal => (
  <Grid key={deal._id} item container xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3} xl={3}>
    <DealCard deal={deal} toggleLike={toggleLike}/>
  </Grid>
))}
```

I did the same for **all product** :

```
{props.deals.map(deal => (
  <Grid key={deal._id} item container xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3} xl={3}>
    <DealCard deal={deal} />
  </Grid>
))}
```

I saw that **if** my **top product** is in my **All Product list**, the components is **linked** (When I change the color of the text, it changes on the component with the same key but no **programmaticaly**).

So my question is : How to change the value of the component linked **programmaticaly** by changing state ?

Comment: You are first telling a problem and then asking how to achieve same thing? Can you read your question again, last two paragraphs?

Comment: I have difficult to explain my problem, I edited my post

Comment: What's the change that you want to reflect in other section (in all products)?

Comment: I need to change my appreciations counter, When a user appreciate the product in the Top Product Section or in the All Product section, I need that both component change their appreciations counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the key value from

```
key={deal._id}
```

to

```
key={`${deal._id}_${deal.appreciations}`}
```

So when your parent state will change, it will trigger the other component as well since key has changed. I hope you have listed the state in parent component and you are updating `deals` array using callbacks without mutating the state.